# Mapping between kiwi specs and BDD terms

Tags: kiwi

Was just trying to wrap my head around how a BDD Story-scenario-Given-when-then maps to Kiwi's describe-context-it as a general rule of thumb if that is possible.. just to get a feel of what should go where when writing tests

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it maps in this sequence

`given-when-then => (describe/context)-it-should`

At least that's how I use it and it works for me.